# Google Analytics daily upload using PHP

Tags: php, upload, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I have to make a PHP script, which will automatically upload data to Google Analytics using API. But there is a problem: [developer guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtDailyUploadGuide) is written for python and java only. Google APIs client library for PHP already have [upload method](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/src/contrib/Google_AnalyticsService.php#79). Please, help me to translate into PHP this java code:

```
  File file = new File("data.csv");
  InputStreamContent mediaContent = new InputStreamContent('application/octet-stream', new FileInputStream(file));
  mediaContent.setLength(file.length());
  Upload upload = analytics.management().dailyUploads().upload("1234",
      "UA-1234-1", "123456789", "2012-10-31", 1, "cost", mediaContent);

  upload.setReset(true);
  DailyUploadAppend append = upload.execute();
```

or this python code:

```
media = MediaFileUpload('data.csv', mimetype='application/octet-stream', resumable=False)

daily_upload = analytics.management().dailyUploads().upload(
      accountId='1234',
      webPropertyId='UA-1234-1',
      customDataSourceId='123456789',
      date='2012-10-31',
      appendNumber=1,
      reset=true,
      type='cost',
      media_body=media).execute()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you gotten this to work yet? What have you tried? I'm no expert but I'll take a crack at it.

The PHP library on their site definitely supports this, there are methods for "dailyUploads" listed in the [Google APIs Client Library for PHP](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/src/contrib/Google_AnalyticsService.php).

```
$dailyUploadsFile = $service->management_dailyUploads->upload(
   '12345678',                    // your accountID
   'UA-12345678-1',               // your web property ID
   'xXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxX',      // your custom data source UID
   '2013-02-04',                  // date
   1,                             // append number
   'cost',                        // type of data
   array(
     "reset" => true,
     "data" => file_get_contents("your-data.csv"),
     'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream',
     'uploadType' => 'media'));
```

This all came from the class "Google_ManagementDailyUploadsServiceResource".

The connection will need to be authenticated. If your input file contains data for multiple days you can include an end date.

Comment: If I've answered your question do you mind selecting this as the answer?